# Catch error when user login

Tags: angularjs

I have a login function that works. But, when the user enters an invalid credential, i of course want to display this. But I cant seem to catch the error.

This is my code that works;

```
    function userAccount($resource) {
        return {

            login: $resource("/Token", null,
            {
                'loginUser': {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        var str = [];
                        for (var d in data)
                            str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" +
                                                encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                        return str.join("&");
                    }

                }
            })
        }
    }

vm.login = function () {
            vm.userData.grant_type = "password";
            vm.userData.userName = vm.userData.email;

            userAccount.login.loginUser(vm.userData,
                function (data) {
                    //login
                },
                function (response) {
                    //run this if error (code 400 or similar error)
                });
        } 
    });
```

What do I need to change, to make sure the last bit is run, when to request fails?

EDIT

I found this in the code, and it looks like that is intercepting the error - but how do i get it to, work with my login function, so i can get an error displayed to the user?

```
.factory('authInterceptor', [
      "$q", "$window", "$location", "currentUser", function ($q, $window, $location, currentUser) {
          return {
              request: function (config) {
                  if (currentUser.getProfile().token) {
                      config.headers = config.headers || {};
                      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token;
                  }
                  return config;
              },
              response: function(response) {
                  return response || $q.when(response);
              },
              responseError: function(rejection) {
                  // error handler
              }
          };
      }
    ])

.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    }])
```

When i remove the last 3 lines, and thereby disabling the interceptor, it works, and the error is caught and showed to the user.
So how to make these work together? :)

Comment: You can use `$promise` to make it promise and you can chain using `.then`. So that you can have success and error functions.

Comment: @Sai But how to incorporate that in to my example code?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your code correctly. Is it working correctly.

Comment: @Sai Yeah, login works - it is just the catching of the error, that does not work

Comment: You can do like `$scope.response = userAccount.login.loginUser(vm.userData);`
Then `$scope.response.$promise.then(function(data) {}, function(error) {});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the rejection or error object back to the login user requset object like this

```
.factory('authInterceptor', [
  "$q", "$window", "$location", "currentUser", function ($q, $window, $location, currentUser) {
      return {
          request: function (config) {
              if (currentUser.getProfile().token) {
                  config.headers = config.headers || {};
                  config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token;
              }
              return config;
          },
          response: function(response) {
              return response || $q.when(response);
          },
          responseError: function(rejection) {
             if(ableToREsolve()){
                 return customRejection
             }
             return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
      };
  }
])
```

This in turn will be caught in :

```
    responseError: function(rejection) {
              // Show in modal or alert
          }
```

For better understanding I suggest  to read on interceptors. Interceptors are of four types:

1. Request 
   2.Request Error 
   3.Response 
   4.Response Error

In simple words, Interceptors get called before actual

- request is passed on to server
- response is delivered to client

So in your case error needs to be returned from interceptor in able to be caught by your request object error function.

request